# pagination to my sample code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination

This is my code I just need to add pagination to my code, I try some other example but it failed to work.

In my HTML code I add pagination raw (<<1,2,3,4>>)
its working in Wordpress using a database connection 
The URL is like `?eventid=#ID`

I checked many codes and example in SO but I failed

```
function ee_attendee_list($atts){
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $EVT_ID = $atts['eventid'];
    $post = get_post( $EVT_ID );   

    echo '

        ';

    $sql = "SELECT ATT_fname, ATT_lname, ATT_email, ATT_address, ATT_phone, STA_ID ";
    $sql .= "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}esp_attendee_meta ";
    $sql .= "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}esp_registration ";
    $sql .= "ON {$wpdb->prefix}esp_attendee_meta.ATT_ID = {$wpdb->prefix}esp_registration.ATT_ID ";
    $sql .= "WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}esp_registration.EVT_ID = %d";

    $attendees = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $post->ID ));
    echo '<table class="blueTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot><tr>
<td colspan="6">';
echo '

<div class="links"><a href="#">&laquo;</a> <a class="active" href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#">4</a> <a href="#">&raquo;</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>';
    foreach($attendees as $attendee){
        $fname = $attendee->ATT_fname;
        $lname = $attendee->ATT_lname;
        $email = $attendee->ATT_email;
        if (empty($attendee->ATT_phone)){ $phone = "No Phone";  } else { $phone = $attendee->ATT_phone; }
        if (empty($attendee->ATT_address)){ $address = "No Address"; } else { $address = $attendee->ATT_address; } 
        $STA_ID = $attendee->STA_ID;


        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$fname $lname</td>
                <td>$email</td>
                <td>$phone</td>
                <td>$address</td>
                <td>$statename</td>
                <td>$country</td>
            </tr>
            ";

    }
    echo "</tbody>
</tr>
</table> ";
}
```

Comment: _but it failed to work._ Okay.. what does that mean?

Comment: i just failed to write pagination code for this query

Comment: _i just failed to write pagination code for this query_ Still very vague...I am out